# MDX calculation should not work on subtotals in excel

Tags: excel, mdx

My granule record-set is like this:

[image: record set]

I use the calculation below to avoid duplicate sum, `[Measures].[TRANSACTION TOTAL AMOUNT] / [Measures].[TRANSACTION ALL COUNT]` so, for `TranId=1;   450 / 3 = 150`

[image: rows view]

it works on every single `TranId` fine and I want to see: `150+80+70 = 300`
excel pivot subtotal. But it shows: `910 / 19 = 47.89`. I don't want it to calculate my mdx calculation for totals or subtotals! I just want dummy summarize

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as written, turning off the subtotal can be done with this added statement in your MDX script:

`[Your Dimension Name].[TranID].[All] = null;`

However I think you are modeling your data incorrectly. You just need to add a new measure group which has one row per TranID and create a Sum measure to get proper details and totals.